# Prove that f has a primitive on the annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on the annulus $D = \{1/2 < |z| < 2\}$. Show that $f$ has a primitive on $D$ if and only if $$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=0$$

Any hints on the main idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $1/z$ in the Laurent series of $f$ centered in $0$ is...

Comment: can  it be proven without using Laurent series

Comment: @NawafMohammedAlhashary, the implication $f$ has primitive $\implies$ $\int = 0$ does not require Laurent series, but I don't know how to prove $\impliedby$ withount Laurent series.